# How to partial fill in missing value based on some condition python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

My dataset have the following missing values:

```
 print(train.shape)
 (54808, 6)

employee_id                0
name                       0
education               2409
age                        0
Salary_hike             4124
length_of_service          0
```

I want to fill the missing salary_hike rows value as 0 based on length_of_service if less than one.

Example:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'employee_id':[103,101,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110],
                      'Name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],
                      'Age' :[20,30,21,24,25,22,27,23,24,21],
                     'length_of_service':[1,2,1,4,5,1,7,1,2,1], 
                      'Salary_hike':[np.nan,5, np.nan, 6, 7,1,9,1,4,np.nan]                ,
                                                                            })
```

For i have identified
How many rows having length of service less than one?

```
(train['length_of_service']<= 1).sum()
5
```

Next i have filleted my data frame with both conditions as below

```
train[(train.length_of_service <=1) & (train['Salary_hike'].isnull())]

        employee_id     Name    Age     length_of_service   Salary_hike
0   103     A   20  1   NaN
2   103     C   21  1   NaN
9   110     J   21  1   NaN
```

Now How do I fill the missing salary hike value as 0 for the above filtered list?

```
    employee_id     Name    Age     length_of_service   Salary_hike
0   103     A   20  1   0
2   103     C   21  1   0
9   110     J   21  1   0
```

I have used the command which mentioned in the comments section like:

```
train.loc[(train.length_of_service==-1) & (train['Salary_hike'].isnull()),'Salary_hike'] = 0
```

But still I am getting missing values as 3.

```
train.isnull().sum()
```

Hello All,

Thanks for the valuable input:

Now it's working after using the below command:

```
train.loc[(train.length_of_service <=1) & (train['Salary_hike'].isnull()),['Salary_hike']]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'length_of_service':[-1,5,4,-8,9,-3,0], 
                      'Salary_hike':[10,np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 8, np.nan]})
train.loc[(train.length_of_service <=1) & (train['Salary_hike'].isnull()),'Salary_hike'] = 0

print (train)
   length_of_service  Salary_hike
0                 -1         10.0
1                  5          NaN
2                  4          5.0
3                 -8          0.0
4                  9          NaN
5                 -3          8.0
6                  0          0.0
```

If need set if values are `-1`:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'length_of_service':[-1,5,4,-1,9,-3,-1], 
                      'Salary_hike':[10,np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 8, np.nan]})
train.loc[(train.length_of_service==-1) & (train['Salary_hike'].isnull()),'Salary_hike'] = 0

print (train)
   length_of_service  Salary_hike
0                 -1         10.0
1                  5          NaN
2                  4          5.0
3                 -1          0.0
4                  9          NaN
5                 -3          8.0
6                 -1          0.0
```

Comment: I need if length of the service is -1 then salary hike missing values needs to be filled with 0

Comment: @thangaraj1980 - then use `train.loc[(train.length_of_service==-1) & (train['Salary_hike'].isnull()),'Salary_hike'] = 0`

Comment: Hi, I used the above command, But  I am getting False/True boolen value. Not filling the missing values

Comment: @thangaraj1980 - It is weird, added sample data for both DataFrames and for me working perfectly, not some typo?

Comment: @thangaraj1980 - So for you `train.loc[(train.length_of_service <=1) & (train['Salary_hike'].isnull()),'Salary_hike'] = 0` not working, but `train.loc[(train.length_of_service <=1) & (train['Salary_hike'].isnull()),['Salary_hike']] = 0` working, with `[]` ? I think here working both solution same.